how to persist user login
The problem is that I can't keep a user logged in with their user id to access supabase's tables to fetch or post data. I have two navigators, one for logged-in users and one for users who are not logged in (i.e., just login and signup routes). I can bypass the login screen with code, but then in that case supabase doesn't recognise the user so won't fetch or post any data.
I have tried everything I could find on the Internet. I have tried using Auth Context Provider, but that made no difference. I have tried all the advice on supabase docs and supabase react tutorials. This has allowed me to bypass the login screen and automatically appear to log in, but the user is not actually logged in. I have tried all the getSession() and getUser() but they didn't help either. I really hope someone here can help me before I actually go insane!
Here is my code for the navigator index.js (minus all the commented out things i have tried!)
const AppNavigator = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.loggedIn);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAuthInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getFromAsyncStorage("AUTH_TOKEN");
        if (!token) {
          return dispatch(authActions.updateLoggedInState(false));
        } else {
          dispatch(authActions.updateLoggedInState(true));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        Toast.show("Oops, something went wrong!");
      }
    };
    fetchAuthInfo();
  }, []);



  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Root.Navigator>
        {loggedIn ? (
          <Root.Screen
            name="MainNavigator"
            component={MainNavigator}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Root.Screen
            name="AuthNavigator"
            component={AuthNavigator}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        )}
        <Root.Screen
          name="ForgotPassword"
          component={ForgotPassword}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Root.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

And here is the code for my login page (well, not the JSX as I think that is fine):
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.loggedIn);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email,
      password,
    });

    if (error) {
      Toast.show(error.message);
      console.log(error);
    }

    if (data.session) {
      await saveToAsyncStorage("AUTH_TOKEN", data.session.access_token);
      dispatch(authActions.updateLoggedInState(true));
      console.log("logged in", data.session.user.id);
    }
  };

When I log in using the login form (when I am not using the code to bypass this screen), the last line there (the console log) works and gives me the user id and all the data is fetched and posted as desired. It is just when I use the code to skip through the login process that the app has no idea who you are.

The main issue you have is that you are trying to manage the auth token by yourself, which is something the Supabase SDK takes care of automatically.
Initialize Supabase passing the AsyncStorage from @react-native-async-storage, and remove any code that you are saving the access token or any tokens to async storage manually by yourself and everything will be just fine.
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  },
})


Thank you that's really helpful. I just wonder how it works with different navigators (MainNavigator, AuthNavigator in particular). How do I check in the navigation index.jsx if the user is authenticated in order to decide which screen to show? I did delete all the storage code and now i can't log in at all on the simulator!

@JosieJones You can call getSession() method to see if a session exists or not. If a session does exist, the user is signed in.
